MAUI: Listview is not visible when adding FlowDirection and Rotation
The ListView is not visible when adding FlowDirection and Rotation properties. The Listview was visible before adding FlowDirection and Rotation.
<ListView 
    -------
    FlowDirection="RightToLeft"
    Rotation="180"
    ------------->
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <ViewCell.View>
                    <StackLayout
                        -------------
                        FlowDirection="LeftToRight"
                        Rotation="180"
                        -------------> 

I found a similar issue here. I have created a sample project to reproduce this issue. Any solutions available?

Did this problem only appear on android platform?

@LiyunZhang-MSFT I only run it on Android device, didn't get a chance to verify it on ios device. I will check and update here

@LiyunZhang-MSFT Verified on ios and no issue on ios platform

Have you narrowed down which property causes the problem?

I have reproduced this problem you can follow up the issue you found.
What I found:

If the value of the Rotation smaller than 90, such as 45 or 10. You can see a part of the ListView.
Even though the listview is not visible when you set Rotation="180", the height and width has value.

So the problem is the center of the listview's rotation.
And for a workaround, you can add a parent view for the ListView and then set Rotation="180" for its parent. Such as:
<Border Rotation="180">
    <ListView 
    -------
    FlowDirection="RightToLeft"

In addition, you can also use the CollectionView instead of the ListView. This issue only appears on ListView.

If we use collectionview how can I add the pull down refresh and ItemAppearing properties, I have both on my listview.

I tried this solution and found it has issues with scrolling. When scrolling to the top, the list goes down, and when scrolling to the bottom, the list goes up.

You can read the official document about Pulling to refresh in the collectionview. And for the ItemAppearing event, you can use the collectionview's RemainingItemsThresholdReached event instead of it. @MatthewPans

And for the new issue about scrolling, can you show more details?

I tried collectionview and facing a few issues, will post it as a new thread.
